# How do you use reverse_lazy with function based views in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

When I run my django app on a production server, I receive an error stating that my urlconf does not contain any patterns. After a few hours of research, I discovered that my problem was mainly due to url template tags that were attempting to do a reverse lookup on the urlconf before the urlconf loaded. This always resulted in an error.

I think that reverse_lazy might solve this issue, as it'd force the urlconf to be loaded first, but I don't know how to apply this to function based views, as the solutions I found online only applied to Class based generic views. Is there a way to fix this problem using reverse_lazy? Or should I try something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```

from the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/  shows this usage for reverse.  I've never tried it with reverse_lazy, but worth a shot.